# What's this ring around the inside of my moka pot?

Tags: espresso, moka

I just bought a Bialetti moka stainless steel pot and when I went to wash it for the first time (before any use) I noticed this rust-looking ring around the inner bottom portion of the top pot where the coffee brews out. I've had aluminum moka pots before but this is my first stainless steel one, so I'm not sure if this is normal from the welding or if I should return the pot for a new one. If anyone has advice I'd greatly appreciate it! [image]

Answer (score -1):

It looks like the seam from when the pot was manufactured and the brown stains will be coffee not rust. If you soak it in some diluted bleach over night, the stain will disappear.
Thanks,
Simon

Comment: The asker explicitly wrote “before first use. That makes a coffee stain unlike, provided they bought a new Moka.